# How make reusable code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code on the link below, and I need to use it several times for any places. I set different value for bars, of course it works wrong. So, the bad answer is set id to each span and copy code for them several times.

Please, give me a tip how to rewrite code that I don't need to repeat again and again.

P.S. yes, I know about progressbar.js and other libraries but in this place I need to handle bar from html elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blackbar > span").each(function() {
    var percentWidth = $('.blackbar > span').data('width');
    $(this).animate({
      width: $(this).data("width") + "%"
    }, 800);
    $({
      countNum: 0
    }).animate({
      countNum: percentWidth
    }, {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $('.barvalue').text(Math.floor(this.countNum)).append(" %");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('.barvalue').text(this.countNum).append(" %");
      }
    });

  });
});
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/SleepyLemur/dyhw00jx/4/)

Comment: You may want to include the HTML and CSS in the question also, rather than requiring the jsfiddle for full comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over each `.barbox`, and then find the span for the bar and the span for the value, and use them appropriately...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".barbox").each(function() {
        var $barbox = $(this);
        var $barSpan = $barbox.find('.blackbar > span');
        var $barValue = $barbox.find('.barvalue');
        var percentWidth = $barSpan.data('width');
        $barSpan.animate({
                width: percentWidth + "%"
        }, 800);
        $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentWidth}, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'linear',
            step: function() {
                $barValue.text(Math.floor(this.countNum) + " %");
            },
            complete: function() {
                $barValue.text(this.countNum + " %");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vsp6vuuh/2/

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/8919job4/

Set variables for $span and the $barvalue.

```
  $(".blackbar > span").each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    var $barvalue = $span.closest('.b-item__barbox.barbox').find('.barvalue');
    var percentWidth = $span.data('width');
    $span.animate({
      width: percentWidth + "%"
    }, 800);
    $({
      countNum: 0
    }).animate({
      countNum: percentWidth
    }, {
      duration: 800,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $barvalue.text(Math.floor(this.countNum)).append(" %");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $barvalue.text(this.countNum).append(" %");
      }
    });

  });
```